# How to reset admin password in Moodle if you don't have access to your database?

Tags: moodle

I tried many ways to reset my admin password but nothing, is there any way to reset Moodle admin password using config.php or something? also, I couldn't find the config.php file, I went through the path /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/, but except for index.html I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

You can reset passwords, including admins, from the command line

```
php admin/cli/reset_password.php
```

or without prompts

```
php admin/cli/reset_password.php --username=admin --password=Newpassword
```

You will need to know the root of the Moodle website though